# How do you output the highest index in the list on Python?

Tags: python

**How do you output the highest index in the list on Python?**

---

Situation.
I'm solving an algorithm problem.
We are unable to solve the problem because of one condition.
So I googled, but I couldn't solve it.

---

**my code**

```
arr = [1,0,0,0,1,1]
```

---

**try code**

```
arr = [1,0,0,0,1,1]
res = []
temp = 0
for i in arr :
    temp = max(i)
    max_index = temp.inedx(temp)
```

---

**i want result output**
so, I want to output the index 5th value within the list above.

**Case**

```
a = [1,1,1,0,0,0] -------> 2
a = [0,1,1,1,0,0] -------> 3
a = [0,0,0,1,1,1] -------> 5
a = [1,0,1,1,0,0] -------> 3
a = [1,1,2,1,0,0] -------> 2
```

It has the same value in the list.

Outputting the highest index among themselves.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be to just take the length of the list and subtract 1...? Why would you even think to do a loop in the first place?

Comment: Highest index, or index of highest element?

Comment: @enke It can't be solved with that method.

Comment: @Amadan The one with the same value in the list. e.g  = [1,1,1,0,0,0] -> 2, [1,1,0,0,1,0] ->4

Comment: @record What?? What does "*the highest index in the list*" mean to you, exactly? Where do you get `2` from that list? The list's `len` is `6`, why would the highest index not be `5`? Your comment is in direct contradiction.

Comment: Please explain by what logic does "highest index" of `[1,1,1,1,0,0]` result in `2`?!?

Comment: I updated the post about the desired output value in detail. (Please see the CASE part.)

Comment: You have edited in some examples from which I can infer the rule to be "the last index of the biggest element", but that does not explain `[1,1,1,1,0,0] -> 2`, which should be `3` by that logic. Also, what would be the result of `[1, 1, 2, 1, 0]`?

Comment: @amadon here was an error in the comments, so I deleted it.

`Assuming that a = [0,1,1,1,0,0] is in the list, output ->3 should appear.`

Comment: You never answered about my additional example (`[1,1,2,1,0]` — or are the elements always just 1/0? If so, please confirm that as well.

Comment: @Amadan yes,[1,1,2,1,0,0] -> `output : 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
len(arr) - 1 - arr[::-1].index(max(arr))
```

`arr[::-1]` produces a reversed list; `.index` finds the first index of an element; `max` finds the highest element. First index of an element in a reversed list is the last index of an element. We then need a bit of arithmetic to unreverse the index.

Alternately:

```
max_v = None
max_i = None
for i, v in enumerate(arr):
    if max_v is None or v >= max_v:
        max_v = v
        max_i = i
print(max_i)
```

Comment: for `arr = [1,1,2,1,0,0]` it produces 3 when it should be 2.

Comment: @enke Oh thanks I forgot to unreverse the index

Answer (score 0):

Simply enumerate the list and once exhausted you get the index:

```py
last = 0
for idx, item in enumerate(your_list):
    if item != 0:
        last = idx  # or with +1, depending on your use-case
print(last)
```

You can be a bit creative with the solution which might cause it being more efficient such as reversing the list ([`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) / `list[::-1]`), halving it (check for odd/even number of elements) and using a look-ahead or use `sum()` and other:

```py
for idx, item in enumerate(data):
    if item != 0 and sum(data[idx + 1:]) == 0:
        last = idx
```

For fetching the index of the highest element in a list, add a check not for `!= 0` but for `== max(your_list)`, preferably store the `max(your_list)` into a variable before your loop so it's calculated only once instead of in all of the iterations.

Comment: This code has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @record How so? Isn't the `last` variable storing the value of the last index of a non-zero value as you've described for example here: `a = [0,1,1,1,0,0] -------> 3`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np
max(numpy.where([0, 0, 1])[0]) # outputs 2
```

`numpy.where` returns a tuple where the first element is an array of indexes where truth-y values are found.

Comment: Is there any other way without using numpy?